# Geany custom folding for custom filetype

Tags: file-type, geany, code-folding

Company i work develops a new programming language which will ease job of engineer. My job is to supply this language with a nice editor which is also involves code folding. I need to have custom code folding which is **not** include "{" and "}". I am working with Geany filetypes. I add new filetype. I want to fold some structure like below.

```
 if %condition%  then                     for each %element% in  %range%  do 
    %statement%                              %statement%  
 else if %condition%  then                end for
    %statement%  
 else
 end if
```

I know my language far from c type , however add such line to my code for enabling syntax coloring.

```
  [settings]
  lexer_filetype=C
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know exact answer but i know how i can dig it up. As far there is no an answer i am going to write how can the answer can be appeared. Using scintilla and its lexers can take us to solution of this problem. Both [Geany](http://www.geany.org/manual/0.14/) and [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html) documentations mention about support of that feature.

Answer (score -1):

Under Debian :

1. `cp /usr/share/geany/filetypes.c ~/.config/geany/filedefs/`
2. `chown myUser:myGroup ~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.c`
3. Edit the file. Under the section `[lexer_properties]` add the line:

   fold.cpp.comment.explicit=1
4. Save the file.
5. Open geany. You are now able to put userfoldings using the default `//{`  and `//}` delimiters in c and in cpp. These do not influence your code because to c and cpp it are comments.